# No puedo deserealizar respuesta JSON a una consulta API en vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

Mi problema es con una consulta a una API mia. Ya he probado con varios ejemplos que vi, inclusive en esta comunidad, pero sigo sin poder solucionar el problema.

La API de donde me traigo los datos es:

https://dosttin.ar/api/public/index.php/usuarios-query-all

El JSON de respuesta es el siguiente:
( he acortado los datos , seleccionando solamente 2 registros )

```json
{
  "totalResults": 2,
  "itemsPerPage": 16,
  "startIndex": 0,
  "entry": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "nombre": "Jor111",
      "apellido": "noselaco",
      "correo": "selac@yahoo.com",
      "obser": "observa"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "nombre": "Jorcon",
      "apellido": "selaco",
      "correo": "reselacsi@yahoo.com",
      "obser": "si"
    }
  ]
}
```

El código :

```
Public Async Function GetUsers() As Task(Of Object)
    Try
        Dim UrlApi As String = "https://dosttin.ar/api/public/index.php/usuarios-query-all"
        Dim WebCliente As New WebClient()

        WebCliente.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        WebCliente.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; " +
                              "Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")

        Dim JsonDevuelto As String = Await WebCliente.DownloadStringTaskAsync(New Uri(UrlApi))

        Dim ListaDevuelta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Cabecera))(JsonDevuelto)
        Return ListaDevuelta

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Function
```

la clase que utilizo:

```
Public Class Cabecera
Public Property totalResults As Integer
Public Property itemsPerPage As Integer
Public Property startIndex As Integer
Public Property entry As List(Of UsersModel)
End Class

Public Class UsersModel
Public Property id As String
Public Property nombre As String
Public Property apellido As String
Public Property correo As String
Public Property obser As String
End Class
```

y el error que me da es:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebAPIpruVB.Cabecera]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'totalResults', line 2, position 19.
```

Si me pueden dar una mano como puedo leer los datos y poder recorrer el array de datos, les agradeceria.

Desde ya Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En un JSON los objetos están envueltos con `{ }` y los arrays con `[ ]`

Tu JSON esperado es

```
{ "totalResults": 2, "itemsPerPage": 16, "startIndex": 0, "entry": [ { "id": "1", "nombre": "Jor111", "apellido": "noselaco", "correo": "selac@yahoo.com", "obser": "observa" }, { "id": "4", "nombre": "Jorcon", "apellido": "selaco", "correo": "reselacsi@yahoo.com", "obser": "si" } ] }
```

Si te fijas en el resultado está todo envuelto dentro de `{ }`, por lo que recibes un objeto.

Entonces esto:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Cabecera))(JsonDevuelto)
```

Debes cambiarlo por esto

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Cabecera)(JsonDevuelto)
```

Adicionalmente te recomiendo

- Usar `HttpClient` en lugar de `WebClient`
- `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` en lugar de `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias!